# Create Data Extension that can't be deleted?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, marketingcloudapi

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a data extension that cannot be deleted? I know it works with DataFolder using the API, with this property:

```
<IsEditable>false</IsEditable>
```

But the DataExtension object does not have that property. Just to see, I added that property when creating a data extension, but it did not make the DE undeletable. I've seen a bit of a hack where you move it to a hidden folder or something and I suppose that could work, but hoping for a better way.

Comment: You cannot. And honestly you would not want to do this. This sounds like a major issue just waiting to happen

Answer (score 0):

Actually this video goes into some detail about hiding the folder that the DE lives in. It's one way to secure your DE.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEwUWJCnfiA